# Crafting a regex for mod_rewrite with more than nine parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite

Say for example, I have a URL in this format:

```
http://example.com/(mobile-or-desktop-flag)/(major-venue-category)/(smaller-venue-category)/(venue-name)/(month)-(day)-(year)/(picture-number)/(user-action-on-picture)/(request-ajax-or-not)
```

where the text in parenthesis represent the parameter data.

and some example URLs are:

```
http://example.com/desktop/big/nightclubs/bloke/jan-1-2015/1/download/no-ajax
http://example.com/desktop/small/lounges/oko-blu/feb-2-2014/6/share/no-ajax
http://example.com/mobile/tiny/bars/honest-lawyer/mar-3-2013/9/report/ajax
```

With mod_rewrite, I know I can use `$1` through `$9` for the first nine parameters, but here, I have 10 parameters, and `$10` is considered first parameter with a zero added to it. See RewriteCond at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I'm just wondering, is there any way one can include a variable 10th parameter in a rewrite rule, or will I have to merge two parameters into one and extract them into two via a server-side script?

Answer (score 1):

> is there any way one can include a variable 10th parameter in a rewrite rule

As far as I'm aware you can only use the backreferences `$0`..`$9` (`$1` to `$9` references the parenthesised/captured groups and `$0` references the entire pattern that is matched) in Apache regex (eg. mod_rewrite, etc) to reference captured groups in the `RewriteRule` pattern (`%0`..`%9` for the last matched `CondPattern`).

Workarounds:

1. Like you suggest, you could merge two or more parameters into one and let your server-side script parse the URL. The *date* (month-day-year) is the obvious one. You could simply use mod_rewrite to validate the URL and let your server-side script parse the entire URL into its component parts (a front-controller).
2. As an extension to the above. You could merge two or more params and rewrite the URL a second time, combining the params into the correct format required by the script you are rewriting to. For example, take the `month-day-year` parameter(s). If the script you were rewriting to required the date in universal date format (year-month-day) then you could first capture and convert this into one parameter (together with the remainder of the URL).
   For example:

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(\w+/[\w-]+/[\w-]+/[\w-]+)/([a-z]{3})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{4})/(.*) /$1/$4-$2-$3/$5
   RewriteRule ^(desktop|mobile)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/(\d{4}-[a-z]{3}-\d{1,2})/(\d{1,3})/(download|share|report)/(no-ajax|ajax) /script.php?platform=$1&majorcat=$2&minorcat=$3&vname=$4&date=$5&picnum=$6&action=$7&ajax=$8 [L]
   ```
3. Avoid *capturing* groups for any groups you don't need in the current rewrite. ie. Make it a non-capturing group by prefixing with `?:`, for example: `(?:desktop|mobile)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also utilize te behavior of .htaccess, remembering that the generated url will be passed again and process the url in cycles, in the first you can deal with a group of parameters, and in the second with the other group...

[image: You can see the flow in this diagram]

The image is Taken from [here](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/introduction-to-redirects)

```
# This is a .htaccess file
# This will match the full pattern, that has to be adapted to any case, in this particular case will match "one/two/three/four/five/six/seven/eight/nine/ten/" ten parameters path
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(all_parameters_matched|processed_first_group)
RewriteRule ^((?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/(?:.+)\/?)$ all_parameters_matched/$1 [QSA,L]

# This deals with the first group of parameters
RewriteRule ^all_parameters_matched\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)$ processed_first_group/$4?param1=$1&param2=$2&param3=$3 [QSA]

# This deals with the second group of parameters
RewriteRule ^processed_first_group\/([^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)\/(.*)$ /script.php?param4=$1&param5=$2&the_rest=$3 [QSA]
```

In the example above it processes only five parameters in two parts, but you could get the idea.